# Can I calculate a standard deviation for the mean of a sample including data points from different populations

Tags: standard-deviation

Lets say I have

- 200 data points from a distribution with standard deviation 4.2, and
- 50 data points from a distribution with standard deviation 3.5.

Can I calculate the standard deviation for the mean of all 250 data points? If so, how?

Comment: Are you assuming that the two distributions have the same unknown mean?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure on that. It's a bit complicated, but what I do know is what the mean of all 250 data points should be.

Comment: @Henry Actually, sorry I'm getting confused. The two distributions have different known means.

Comment: If you know the individual population means and standard deviations, then you can combine them via the second moment about $0$ to get an overall mean of $\frac{1}{n_1+n_2}\left(n_1\mu_1+n_2\mu_2\right)$ and standard deviation of $\sqrt{\frac{1}{n_1+n_2}\left(n_1\sigma_1^2+n_1\mu_1^2 + n_2\sigma_2^2+n_2\mu_2^2\right) - \left(\frac{1}{n_1+n_2}\left(n_1\mu_1+n_2\mu_2\right)\right)^2}$  though there are probably more numerically stable ways of expressing this